# Data not getting inserted in db in django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-views

Hi I am trying to select data from a dropdown list and then save it in Category model.There is no problem in retrieving the data but when i check it using Category.objects.all(), I get this

```
<QuerySet [<Category: Category object>, <Category: Category object>, <Category: Category object>, <Category: Category object>]>
```

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Category(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category= models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py:

```
    def get_category(request):

    cname = request.POST.get("dropdown1")
    user = request.session.get('user')
    obj=Category(user_id=user,category=cname)
    obj.save()
    return HttpResponse("Registeration succesfull")
```

With `get_category` i am trying to save entry selected from dropdown.It works fine but i guess nothing is being stored in the db.

I tried running this

```
Category.objects.get(category = "abc")
I get this error:

DoesNotExist: Category matching query does not exist.
```

Can someone tell if this is not the right way to insert data in db.

Comment: try to print cname and user before the obj.save() and check what are you getting

Comment: @Exprator it prints the selected data from dropdown and userID

Comment: can you show the data after printing

Comment: @Exprator  Netowrks 66-> This is what i get after printing cname and user

Comment: if the category name is coming as Networks how are you going to get a category name called abc??

Comment: @Exprator yes that was just for example.Now when i try Category.objects.get(category="Networks")  ..I get <Category:Category object>

Answer (score 0):

you are getting category object in Category.objects.all() because you have not specified any string or unicode name for the instances.
in your model append these

```
class Category(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.category
```

you can also replace `__str__` with `__unicode__` 
now the category names will be visible in the queryset.

Comment: if this helped you please upvote and mark as true. thank you @swati_singh